# Where to call RaiseCanExecuteChanged?

Tags: mvvm, mvvm-light, relaycommand

I'm working with MVVM Light Toolkit, and I'd like to create a `RelayCommand`.

If my ViewModel has some `String` properties, which ones call the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` in the setters, everything works fine, the command can be executed when I want.

But if I change the code, I create a Model class X, and it contains all of these properties, the ViewModel contains a property with type X, where should I call the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged`? In the Model class makes no sense, and the setter of the X in the ViewModel is not called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will likely need to subscribe to the Model class `PropertyChanged` event, and raise your RaiseCanExecuteChanged  when the model property changes.

Comment: So simple and obvious... Thanks!

Comment: @Vishal In the VM constructor, when you set the model, do something like `model.PropertyChanged += (o,e) => this.command.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();`

Comment: I have tried that but still CanExecute method does not fire. I have a Property Called NewOrder in my VM which is of type Order. Inside order I have 3-4 simple string and int properrties and a property of type ICollection<Item>. So, is there any extra work needed for me to do here??